# Provider Management : Could not establish a connection to the database

Tags: sql, asp.net, database

i get error when test AspNetSqlProvider in provider manager on  Web Site Administration Tool Site Administration Tool

i created the SQL Server database with aspnet_regsql.exe

but still have the same error:

Provider Management: Could not establish a connection to the database. 
If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider.

I have SQL Express 2012 , VS ultimate 2013, and windows 8.

The procedure that I follow

**1-** Create new website with membership:[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c(v=vs.90).aspx][1]

**2-** When I reached ASP.NET Configuration. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9o1ZExV5Jg

**3-** use **aspnet_regsql.exe wizard** to create new database **aspnetdb** (I used the same SQL authentication credentials of SQL express server ).

**4-** **TCP/IP and Names pipes Enabled**

**5-** ** SQL server and browser is running**

and my **cofig.web** file ;

```
<connectionStrings>
 <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
 <add   name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=SAHARPC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=true;AttachDBFilename=C:\Users\Saharhp\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\web44\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" 

providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and the same in **maching.config**

That's all steps that i did. and still same error (Security tab is working normally).

Any help please?

**my all config.web code**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>

      <authentication mode="Forms" >
          <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"
            name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
          <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
      <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
          <providers>
              <clear />
              <add
                name="SqlProvider"
                type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
                connectionStringName="MySqlConnection"
                applicationName="MyApplication"
                enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                enablePasswordReset="true"
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
                requiresUniqueEmail="true"
                passwordFormat="Hashed" />
          </providers>
      </membership>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />

    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

  </system.web>


      <connectionStrings>
          <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
          <add   name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=SAHARPC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=true;AttachDBFilename=C:\Users\Saharhp\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\web44\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"

         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>  

      </connectionStrings>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<system.data>        
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
            <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data></configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have any other way of verifying that you created the database when running aspnet_regsql?

Comment: What do you mean by verifying DB? and how can I do that? I didn't verify it.. can you tell me some steps.. thanks

Comment: he's asking if the file aspnetdb.mdf exists on the file system where you're trying to access it.  Also can you open it with sql server management studio express?

Comment: yea sure . its available on app_data folder in the projects folder.I don't have SQL server management studio express installed on my PC. I din't find compatible version for windows 8!. please keep help me I spent all yesterday searching with no benefit –

Comment: hi, i checked my folders now first i didn't find the app_data folder in vs 2013 project folder , instead its in my wwwroot folder . i think this because i used http location when create the new website according to the tutorial. is that ok? or i need to change the folder to vs 2013?

Comment: Can you post other part of your web.config?

Comment: @Rahul  code added to question above.

Comment: i use ASP.NET Web Page Razor 2.

Answer (score 0):

There is the problem. In your `<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider"` you are using different connection string name than the one you have as shown below

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  ........
            connectionStringName="MySqlConnection" <-Here
```

It should be

```
connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
```

Also, try changing your connection string to be below, notice I have omitted `attachedDBfilename` attribute

```
<connectionStrings>
 <Clear/>
 <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=SAHARPC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=true; providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

If this don't work then try using username/password of your SQL Server instead of `Integrated Security` like

```
 <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=SAHARPC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb; uid=sqlusername; pwd=password"; providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: i have changed it to "LocalSqlServer" but still the same ?

Comment: it seems the settings don't have any affect on the database connection. is there any steps or tutorial to create membership website with asp.net?

Comment: Comeon, I clearly mentioned in answer that change your connectionstring name to `LocalSqlServer`. That's what exactly the error saying.